# Solidity stuck at mining transaction

Tags: solidity, mining, testnets, morden, metamask

I am trying to deploy a contract in the ethereum blockchain with solidity. When i press the create button directly under it, a message saying

> "Waiting for transaction to be mined..."

shows up indefinitely. The contract i am trying to deploy is pretty simple and straight forward and i got it from a youtube tutorial. In the tutorial, after pressing the create button the metamask plugin pops up a message to make sure you want to deploy the contract which in my case it doesn't since it is stuck at "Waiting for transaction to be mined... ".
Any ideas why this is happening? Thank you in advance

(in metamask i am connected to the testnet morden)

Comment: Are you using a private, the testnet or mainnet?

Answer (score 2):

The morden testnet is basically dead at this point, and really only exists for the sake of viewing old Dapps.  I recommend using the Ropsten testnet instead, which should show up in your MetaMask provider menu in the top left.

For an explanation of why Morden died, read this:

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Ethereum testnet was reset and the new testnet is called Ropsten. Since the change, the solidity web compiler had some issues and will hopefully be resolved soon. Meanwhile try to use clients such as geth or parity or just download mist. (thanks to shlomi zeltsinger)