# Waiting for transaction to be mined

Tags: mining, testnets, remix, ropsten, metamask

When calling any method on a contract https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xabc7a3a72af1f94ff6029ef01bc0f7c49e2ed637 using Browser Solidity https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/ on Ropsten Testnet, the message "Waiting for transaction to be mined..." never quits and transaction doesn't even show at the origin account https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xe5f68950d479fab12797dabbe5a4b0d88ec7a722

The contract was deployed yesterday and I could call methods using Metamask with no problems. But today, it isn't working anymore...

People is suffering similar situation at [Solidity stuck at mining transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10341/solidity-stuck-at-mining-transaction) but in this case I am working with new Ropsten testnet and Metamask.

Any idea how to solve this issue? How can I trace metamask transaction to find out where it gets stuck? Thx!

24 hours later I realize the call transaction have been performed at https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xf087a137e7f4962260da26928d205cabd71eed68fd79f8f35fb1027073f03812

It seems it took a lot of time to mine, but I don't know exactly how much nor the reasons to that delay.

Comment: Did you by any chance try submitting a low gas price transaction before it stopped working?

Comment: Not that I knew... Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the Ropsten testnet has been subject to some attacks recently, and that has slowed down much of its performance.  MetaMask is adding support for additional test networks soon, so that may be the problem.